# Matlab Simulink flip video vertically

Tags: matlab, video, simulink, flip, mirror

I have made some modifications in original **Simulink Barcode Recognition Tool** in order to make some research. It is necessary to scan some codes from smartphones as quickly as is it possible.

Now it is very inconvenient to put device in proper position due to that video is displayed flipped vertically (not like in mirror).

Is it possible to flip it one more time using only **Simulink**?

I have tried to use negative scale but it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I've used "Matlab function" block from simulink/User-Defined Functions and wrote code inside:

```
function y = fcn(u)

y = flip(u,2);
```